# Is it possible to use Java 8 to avoid java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen in GWT Devmode

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.5, java-8

I came across a recent article on Java 8 related to [memory management](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.in/2013/02/java-8-from-permgen-to-metaspace.html) w.r.t to PermGen space.

Is there any way we can use  Java 8 [Metaspace](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace) with GWT Dev mode to improve GWT Dev mode utility and performance.

**Edit -**
I understand the part the source code needs to be JDK 6 compatible to be compilable for javascript. I am guessing no such restriction need to apply for memory management in dev mode

Answer (score 1):

[As pointed out from Thomas Broyer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/eQtWYgkUB04), you can only use code of java 6 source.

It is possible to run with JDK 7 - so maybe it should also run with JDK 8, but you still can only use code of Java 6.

Comment: I understand that part the source code needs to be JDK 6 compatible to be compilable for javascript. I am guessing no such restriction need to apply for memory management in dev mode... i am trying this out with IntelliJIdea12 and Java8 beta release. It would be cool if somebody in GWT Dev team weighs in.... i will post this across gwt forums once i have the sample stuff in my box...

Comment: I'm intressted to, hope somebody will come across.